# Jaeger Tracing Config Endpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot, jaeger

I'm trying setting up a spring application which use Jaeger/Prometheus.
I already configured Prometheus successfully by prometheus.yaml file, but I haven't understood how configure Jaeger target endpoint.
Must I create a new yaml file and specify into it the configuration? If yes, with which syntax?

Answer (score 0):

The Jaeger tracer (the part that runs along with your application) will send spans via UDP to an agent running on localhost by default. If your agent is somewhere else, set the `JAEGER_AGENT_HOST`/`JAEGER_AGENT_PORT` env vars accordingly. If you don't want an agent running on localhost and want to access a Jaeger Collector directly via HTTP, then set the `JAEGER_ENDPOINT` env var.

More info about these env vars can be found in the [documentation](https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.7/client-features/) or here:
https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-client-java/tree/master/jaeger-core#configuration-via-environment

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying.
i found the const like  io.jaegertracing.Configuration.JAEGER_ENDPOINT, but they're const, so how should i configure them without using reflection?
and then, wich field shoul for setting only host and port?
thank you

Comment: Those are environment variables. The constant you found reflects the name of the env var that is expected to be set. Look at the documentation I linked in my reply for more details about how to set it and what is the expected value...